# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: in must not be null

Tags: java, eclipse, opennlp

I tried to use OpenNLP library to use its sentencedetector and I try to write the following code but I got exception which is related to the address of this **en-sent.bin** file but I do not know how to address this file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;
public class SentenceDetect 
{

       private SentenceDetectorME sentenceDetector;

        public void init()
        {
            /** Load and initialize the sentence detection model */

            InputStream modelIn = null;
            SentenceModel model = null;

            try {

                modelIn = SentenceDetect.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Tokenizer/models/en-sent.bin");
                model = new SentenceModel(modelIn); //*<- line 36*
                }
            catch (IOException e) 
                {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
            finally {
                  if (modelIn != null) {
                        try {
                          modelIn.close();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {}
                      }
                }

            sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);

        }

        public String[] getSentences(String longSentence)
        {
            return sentenceDetector.sentDetect(longSentence);
        }

}
```

The Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       SentenceDetect d = new SentenceDetect();


       d.init();   ///*<- line 10*

       String[] s = d.getSentences("This is sentence #1. This is Sentence #2");

       System.out.println( s[0] );  // Should be the first sentence

       System.out.println( s[1] );  // Should be the second sentence

    }
```

The following image shows the hierarchically of my project (sorry about the picture I use Ubuntu but I do not know have use print-screen button here):

[image]

The whole error is:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: in must not be null!
at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:179)
at opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel.<init>(SentenceModel.java:95)
at SentenceDetect.init(SentenceDetect.java:36)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)`
```

I tried these paths but I got the same error:

- /Tokenizer/models/en-sent.bin
- /models/en-sent.bin
- models/en-sent.bin
- /home/suri/workspace/2/Tokenizer/models/en-sent.bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your path to

```
 .getResourceAsStream("en-sent.bin");
```

Since getResourceAsStream read a package and these files (.bin) are in your source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  .getResourceAsStream("Tokenizer/models/en-sent.bin");
```

to

```
 .getResourceAsStream("models/en-sent.bin");
```

You have "Tokenizer" in the path which is the name of your project, which is irrelevant, so you just remove that bit! :)

Comment: @FumnleWumble I tried that But I got the same error for same line

Comment: @Suri could you tell me the whole error from the console? Just copy paste it. I want to know exactly what it says.

Comment: @FumnleWumble the line of code cause Exception and whole error from the console was added in my question.

Comment: @suri Well I'm sorry, I don't know :|

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`, the file must be in your classpath. Right-click the "models" folder in eclipse "build path" -> "use as source folder". Then make sure your path matches the folder structure. If you maintain what you have in the photograph, that would be "models/en-sent.bin".

If you expect that these `.bin` files to typically reside outside of your built `.jar` file, you should use construct a `FileInputStream` instead which can take absolute filesystem paths.